# Issue with UIScrollView and parallax effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to replicate something similar to Android's collapsing toolbar (see this [link](https://crazyaboutandroid.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/ezgif-1326081383.gif) to understand the effect I am trying to achieve). I found a nice turnaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202094/4772647).

My main `UIScrollView` is named `fgScrollView` and the secondary which is pinned on top is named `bgScrollView`. The whole `UIViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

I pin the `fgScrollView` to the Container View. I pin the `bgScrollView` top, right and left to the `fgScrollView` and I give it a steady height of **220**, and I place inside the `bgScrollView` a `UIImageView` which I also pin to all sides and I give it a height of **220**. (All pins are with 0 distance)

This is how it looks from the IB (the `UILabel` that you see in the hierarchy is placed there to give a scrollable height to the `fgScrollView`):

[image]

[image]

In the `scrollViewDidScroll` method I set:

```
bgScrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y * 1.4
```

(I have already set only the fgScrollView to be the delegate and I chose the 1.4 randomly) and in **Interface Builder** I choose the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** option.

The result is this in the beginning:

[image]

but as soon as I click to scroll up this happens (you can see the gap - it stops being pinned to the top):

[image]

From thereon it stays like that when I scroll to the top.

I uncheck the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** option and a strange thing that I notice is that the image does not go under the navigation bar, although I have checked the options **Under Top** and **Bottom Bars**:

[image]

And when I start scrolling this happens:

[image]

and it stays like that even when I scroll back to the top.

I tried to fix the issue programmatically. I add the navigation bar and status bar heights and I declare this:

```
fgScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CGRectGetHeight((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!) + CGRectGetHeight(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame), left: 0,
bottom: CGRectGetHeight((self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame)!), right: 0)
```

and the result is this:

[image]

Any clues?...

Comment: The simplest approach is to use storyboard by setting the proper constraint, here is one example of it https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/ScrollviewParallax